The name of tripod part that came off that known on market
How to get the name of kit/part of the tripod that missed out ie. came off as shown below in order to have it ready to be mounted with a common/cheap Canon auto focus camera or preferably all/most common cameras of that such and the manual focus too.
It's Mars PT-21 (likely discontinued) tripod product

Hopefully one can correctly guide me to the market name of this part common people recognize or are familiar with, preferably would elaborate its info detail.
Thanks much before

You will probably not find the missing part of the tripod head, at least for less than the price of a complete tripod.
See if you can unscrew the rest, and if you end up with a 3/8" or 1/4" screw you can mount a standard tripod ballhead such as this.

Honestly, it's a giveaway. So most likely tripod head/ballhead is cracked, broken, on which no seller/one would provide it  viable to be attached as on that pictured condition, wouldn't?
